# Can a non-ERC20 contract user delegatecall to an ERC20's functions?

Tags: solidity, erc-20

If ContractA is a non-ERC20 and/or does not implement the same storages as the ERC20 it is referencing (let's say USDC's contract), will it be possible to use `delegatecall` so that `msg.sender` of ContractA's function can call USDC contract's `approve, transfer,` etc functions?

If not, what's a good use case for `delegatecall`? If it only updates the storages in ContractA, why would we use another contract's functions vs writing it to update locally? asides from the ease of using a library's logic to update local storage.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> will it be possible to use delegatecall so that msg.sender of ContractA's function can call USDC contract's approve, transfer, etc functions?

Not that way, because it would be updating storage in ContractA, probably with disastrous consequences. But ContractA could call out to USDC and interact in the normal way. That might do the trick, or it might fall short of the goal. A limitation would that you can't progammatically build ContractA to spend someone else's money. The token owner has to approve it, by design.

> If not, what's a good use case for delegatecall

Although it's not technically how these are *implemented*, it may help one develop intuition if this is thought of as importing executable code and running it on the fly.

Libraries and delegation are useful, and many projects use them. Three popular patterns/uses would be:

1. Upgradeable contracts using the Proxy pattern. A contract (the Proxy) is deployed to a fixed address (as they all are), but it delegates execution of everything to an *implementation* contract. The implementation can be written in the usual way. The Proxy just acts as a two-way relay, sending inputs forward and returning responses back, without ever considering higher-order concerns. Provided the Proxy has a way for an admin to input a new *implementation* address, then the implementation is upgradeable.
2. Creating new methods for types, or creating types. Methods can be added to Solidity types, effectively creating new types. E.g., `using MyCoolTypeLib for uint256;`, then `bool isEven = someNumber.isEven();`
3. Addresses the maximum contract size. Rather an extension of #2, libraries offer another way to modularize code, re-use deployed code, and reduce the size of contracts that threaten the bytecode size limit, because `delegate` is a small footprint, and it can summon something with a large footprint. When a contract gets too large, libraries can help externalize code while maintaining functionality.

Hope it helps.